# Wordpress menu parent item only, CSS targeting

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, css-selectors

Logic escapes me for two days on what I'm trying to achieve, which is targeting certain class elements in the wordpress menu with CSS. It is usually simple really for me, but something (small usually) is making me battle.

I need to apply a small background image behind the menu item text to the "active" or "current" menu item. But this must apply ONLY to the parent menu items (not on any of the child/submenu dropdown items). Applying the background image is fine, so that's not the issue. It's targeting only on the parent item that's the issue.

I've tried variations of the following CSS (forgot about the background image for now, I'm keeping it simple here, to resolve the targeting) to make the current/active PARENT menu item text turn red:

```
.main-navigation div ul li.current-menu-parent a:not(.sub-menu)
{color: red !important;}
```

(I have commented out this custom CSS on the website, to prevent confusion)

The `:not` pseudo I thought would do the trick but it's possibly my failure at syntax, even though I googled it, to which I may learn something further about CSS today, when resolved.

It's not working how I expect it to. Any ideas? I might revert back here again if I battle with the background image, but I suspect once the 'CSS targeting' is worked out, that shouldn't be an issue to apply.

Thank you brainy people :)

[image]

Comment: [**Is there a CSS parent selector?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?rq=1) = NO.

Comment: can you share image or screenshot

Comment: Updated my original post with screenshot showing menu drop down and developer tools open showing tags and classes.

Comment: @Paulie_D Reading the thread you posted, I'm assuming then Jquery the solution?

Comment: @Mario JQuery is a solution certainly.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks. It baffles my mind as to why CSS can't do it. It's not anything ununual than applying a rule to a certain class and not any other's beneath the parent tag, which is usually what CSS does. As in the first `:not` example in this post https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/. Nevertheless, I'll explore some jQuery.

Answer (score 3):

### Use the `>` CSS selector

The answer is more simple than you think: use the `>` CSS selector. See articles [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_gt.asp).

WP provides plethora of classes to work with. Also: Do a Google search for "wordpress menu class walker function" and you can generate some more convenience classes, perhaps identify each level of menu e.g. ".top-level", ".second-level", etc.

It would be overkill to use Javascript (e.g. jQuery) in this case. However, it would be a different story if you're using an `eventlistener` and need to get the parent of the clicked target; in that case you DO need JS because as others have mentioned CSS doesn't yet have a parent selector yet (seems like it's coming in CSS4).

For example:
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/MarsAndBack/pen/dygmRxb)

```css
/* Target top level only */
.my_navigation > li > a {
    background-color: yellow;
}

/* Or perhaps target only top-level with children */
.my_navigation > .has_children > a {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Only top-level parents get styled:</h1>
  <ul class="my_navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li class="current_link has_children">
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2a</a></li>
        <li class="current_link has_children"><a href="#">Link 2b</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link I</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link II</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2c</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2d</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3a</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3b</a></li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: parent class could be also ..menu-item-has-children

Answer (score 0):

try below, this will select the `a` tag which is direct child of `li.current-menu-parent`.

```
.main-navigation div ul li.current-menu-parent > a{color: red !important;}
```

Comment: I tried your CSS, no effect. In fact nothing went red.

Answer (score 0):

Seems jQuery was the way to go for the solution, based on the thread [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector?rq=1) posted by @Paulie_D, thank you!

My jQuery solution below targeting only the **active parent menu item** and inserting a small background image on the `<li>` menu tag. You can see the yellow 'paint swish' image happening in the screenshot below.

The `.not` is used to exclude targeting the dropdown submenu items (their class is .sub-menu):

```
$('.main-navigation .current-menu-item, .main-navigation .current-menu-parent').not('.sub-menu li').css(
    {
    'background-image':'url(PATH TO YOUR IMAGE HERE)',
    'background-size': '100% 50px',
    'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
    'background-position': 'center'
    }
);
```

[image]
Thanks for your input. I learnt something today.